# Why does the pipe, in a terminal command line, no longer work under MacOS Monterey 12.3.1?

Tags: c, shell, terminal, macos-monterey

Since the latest MacOs Monterey 12.3.1 update, the pipe no longer works in the following command line :

```
gcc *.c | ./a.out
```

I want to compile and run, at the same time, a .c file, which I could do before.

Comment: Are you sure you did this?  Why would you send the output of gcc to your program?  It seems more likely you were doing `gcc *.c; ./a.out` or `gcc *.c && ./a.out`

Comment: In any case, I can't think of any *nix OS in which the pipe would ever have worked as you describe.  The command on the right side of the pipe will often be executed before the command on the left side starts, and it certainly won't wait for the command on the left to be complete.  If you already have an existing `a.out`, then this could "work", but the process running on the RHS would not be the executable created by the `gcc` on the left.

Comment: Commands in a pipeline are executed simultaneously. You can't run the program before it is compiled. Before, you were probably running the _previously_ compiled `a.out`. Replace `|` with `&&`, to run `a.out` if the compilation completed successfully (and hence `a.out` is new).